# Printing out csv rows apart from first row

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a CSV file in Python, and then print out every row apart from the first row.

I know how to print out all the rows:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

And the only way I can think of not printing out the first row is:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i != 0:
            print row
```

But this doesn't seem very elegant. Any other solutions?

Comment: `for row in itertools.islice(reader, 1, None):` would also work

Comment: ... and yet, in the search for elegance, somehow to my eyes at least, explictly reading the header row and noting that you're dumping it seems like "the way to go".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`csv` reader objects are iterators, which means you can skip single entries using `next()`:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader) # just ignore the result
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: +1.  I deal with csv quite a bit and this is exactly what I do.  For some reason I always comment it: `next(reader) # skip header row`